# Calendar style date picker in Hybrid Apps (Cordova/Phonegap)

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, cordova, datepicker

May be my question would be redundant but is there a solution to show native calendar style datepicker in ANDROID and IOS in Cordova/Phonegap apps. I have searched a lot for the solution but no luck. Only thing I found that there is a calendar style datepicker available in android atleast (not sure about IOS) as mentioned here http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/06/options-for-datepicker-to-display-or.html. but no idea how to develop this in phonegap hybrid apps

I have tried HTML5 Input Date type but its shows as spinners.

I have an alternate solution to use jQueryMobile UI or similar controls but before I try these controls I want to be sure that showing native calendar style datepicker is not possible in hybrid apps. Does anybody have an solution for my requirement .

I have tried this plugin [EddyVerbruggenCalendar-PhoneGap-Plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin.git) but it is mainly for events and activites not for date selection.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: iPhone's native datepicker has the spinner style. If you want calendar style datepicker, iPads support that type.

Comment: @IIlove2Code Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @mjabraham Actually not, none of the plugins shows date picker in calendar style. I have resolved this in my app by designing our own calendar style date picker using HTML5 and css .

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of plugins for date pickers

Here you have some of them:

https://github.com/kdileep1990/com.dileep.plugins.datepicker/

https://github.com/VitaliiBlagodir/cordova-plugin-datepicker

You can search datepicker on plugins.cordova.io

http://plugins.cordova.io/#/search?search=datepicker

or on https://build.phonegap.com/plugins

Comment: Does any of these plugins shows datepicker in calendar style? I dont think so.

Comment: they show the native date pickers, on the link you posted they use a native date picker displayed as a calendar, so it might be possible, but I haven't tested all of them. On iOS no, there is no date picker with calendar appearance, it's like a wheel.

Answer (score 0):

There is a easy way.
Angular datepicker is an angularjs directive that generates a datepicker calendar on your input element.
IOS or Android both OK.
https://github.com/720kb/angular-datepicker

Comment: in my case it does not show any UI. on Android, it is just considering input as a textbox. i am using Cordova-ionoic on Visual Studio 2015

Answer (score 0):

I went through the same trouble and found a solution in the following link

[How to get Calender view in corodva wrapper](https://github.com/VitaliiBlagodir/cordova-plugin-datepicker/issues/241)

So what you have to do is use the `cordova-plugin-datepicker` in your mobile wrapper and then add the following code to your code.

```
this.datePicker.show({
  date: new Date(),
  mode: 'date',
  androidTheme: 5
}).then(
  date => console.log('Got date: ', date),
  err => console.log('Error occurred while getting date: ', err)
);
```

Here android theme 5 is for light theme and 4 is for dark theme.